# Xamarin Android - Archive for Publishing in 'Release' leads to 'Package Creation failed' error in Visual Studio Mac

Tags: android, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, build

I try to publish my Android application built with Xamarin Native and run into an error.

- I use Visual Studio for Mac Community (Version 7.2)
- Select 'Release';
- Select 'Archive for Publishing', then it builds
- And ... I get the error 'Package Creation failed'
- All errors the compiler points out are classes from the project which reside in another project 'Portable library'
- It builds normal in 'Debug' and 'Release'
- 'Archive to Publish' even works in 'Debug', but of course that's not releasable
- This project has been already release like this several times successfully

I have tried various solutions which all failed
- Change the 'Linking-Mode'
- Reference the library again
- Build library first in Release mode
- Clean, Rebuild Debug first, then Release, then Archive
- Restart/Update Visual Studio
- Deleted obj and bin folders

No success, so I have no guess left what I can do. But it somehow must miss out the Portable library from the Release-Archive.

Help much appreciated

Comment: The problem is still there, but building the same code base in Visual Studio Windows worked without a problem while it failed on two different Macs. At least I got the release done but I think something in Visual Studio Mac broke.